# Console window in C#?

Tags: c#, java, console

Well I am attempting to make a Java IDE in C#, and I have everything done, but I don't know how I would make a console window at the bottom of the GUI window that will display the output of the Java code.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a Winforms application, then change its output type to `console application` in `Projects/Properties` menu. Now you will have a winforms app together with a console window.

Comment: You use a (readonly) textbox...you modify the contents of the textbox based on the results of...whatever is going on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be misreading your question, and if I am I apologize, but the [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class, which you will use to start the user's program, has the [StandardOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx) and [StandardError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror.aspx) properties, which you can use to get the output of the program as it runs and display it to a window.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have a full command prompt implemented (open source) so you can explore how to use `UIParent` to do it. Now, this is Windows Forms but if you want it to be WPF then just host it as a control:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2366/Command-Prompt-Explorer-Bar